# how to make Scroll like this with text fill in scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, dom-events

( http://clapat.ro/themes/hervin-wordpress/ )

i have done scroll effect with more error like this

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
  pagination: ".swiper-pagination",
  direction: "vertical",

  slidesPerView: 1,
  paginationClickable: true,

  spaceBetween: 0,
  effect: "coverflow",
  coverflowEffect: {
    rotate: 5,
    slideShadows: true,
    modifier: 0,
    stretch: 10,
    depth: 300,
  },
  mousewheel: {
    releaseOnEdges: true,
    sensitivity: 50,
  },
  observer: true,
  observeParents: true,
  parallax: true,
  speed: 600,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },
});
```

and result same here
https://swiperjs.com/demos/270-mousewheel-control.html

Now I need any idea to fill in the text in the scroll like link above

Answer (score 0):

you probably don't need Swiper for this
this effect can be achieved by some parallax techniques
you may need some 3rd party library to make your life easier

if you are using react you may use FramerMotion or spring
if you are using vanilla javascript you can find dozens of parallax scrolling libraries you may check [this one](https://simpleparallax.com/)

Comment: I can't find anything related to the mouse wheels for which I am using the swiper